# How to get Facebook Proxy Email Address simply

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm building a facebook web app.
How can I get Proxy Email Address(@proxyemail.facebook.com) using facebook graph api by default?

1. If a facebook app requires "email" permission in the authorization dialog, the api returns User's Email Address(Not Proxy Email Address).
2. If the user turns ON a facebook app notification setting in their facebook settings, the api returns the Proxy Email Address.

I think both solutions are not good, because many users don't want to give their E-mail address to external apps if possible and can't turn ON the setting easily.
I want to know how to get Proxy Email Address by default.

If there is no way to get the address, can I request such a function to facebook?